# Polygon and circle algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, polygon

Question here:

Given a polygon P, a circle C_init, and a direction D, let C_init move along D, it might have collision with P (C_target below). How to calculate the distance between C_init and C_target?

[image: IMAGE HERE]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Given that computing the perpendicular distance between a point and a line is a well hashed-out problem, do the following:

1. Find a parametrization of the line along which you're moving
2. Solve for the value of the parameter that gives you a distance R to each line of the polygon
3. Select the first solution that lies within the line segment of the corresponding polygon side.
4. Convert the parameter to distance on the line.

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. why not?

Comment: It doesn't take into account collisions with vertices, which are different from collisions with edges.

Answer (score 0):

When the circle collides with the line segment, the centre of the circle lies on the offset segment (the lozenge shape around the segment).

[image: Offset segment]

One easy way to compute the intersection is to place a circle of radius R at each vertex of the polygon, offset each edge outwards by R, and intersect the ray shooting from the centre of your moving circle with each of the new circles and offset edges. The closest intersection point would be your collision point.

As the picture shows, there is no need to place a circle at reflex angles (>2π) of the polygon as the circle can never collide with such vertices.

[image: Offset polygon]

Answer (score 0):

Draw a parallel to the side that will be hit, at a distance equal to the radius and take the intersection between this line and the trajectory.

You will need a little of analytical/vectorial geometry (I can't guess how familiar you are with these). The parallel can be built by computing a unit vector in the direction of the side, then rotating it by 90° and multiplying by the radius; then if you add this to the vertices of the side, you obtain two points of the parallel.

To obtain the intersection write the parametric equation of the trajectory  and the implicit equation of the parallel. By plugging the first in the second, you obtain an easy first degree equation, giving you the parameter t of the equation of the trajectory (assuming 0 at Cinit and 1 at a unit distance along the trajectory).

[image]

---

This is not the whole story. If you don't know which side will be hit first, you need to determine this. Repeat the computation for all sides, this time using the parametric equation of the parallels and the implicit equation of the trajectory. The value of the parameter must be in range [0, 1], otherwise he corresponding side cannot be hit. If there is an intersection, consider the value of t computed as before. Then the side that will be hit is the one with the smallest (positive) value of t.

---

But this is not yet the whole story: the circle might hit a vertex rather than a side. To check this, draw a circle around every vertex and find the intersection with the trajectory. This time, use the implicit equation of the circle and you will get a quadratic equation in t. If it has no root, the vertex cannot be hit. Otherwise, take the smallest root and compare to the smallest t found when hitting the sides. The the overall smallest t.